# Generate all transition of finite state machine from SCXML file

Tags: java, scxml, apache-commons-scxml

I've state machine implemented with SCXML and i need to know how can i get all transitions from start to end in order to make test cases for the state machine

Answer (score 0):

Because SCXML is just XML, you can query it using xpath. For example, you can find all transitions using the following xpath query: `//transition`

You can find an example of how to use xpath in Java here: https://www.journaldev.com/1194/java-xpath-example-tutorial

Comment: Thanks , 
i'll check xpath